How to create GCP document AI custom extractor with generative AI model and update its schema from .net app
I need to create from a .net application GCP document AI custom extractor that is configured to use generative AI model and I need to update its schema with proper labels. I tried to achieve this with Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1 nuget. The snippet I tried to use for creation of processor:
var response = await _client.CreateProcessorAsync(new CreateProcessorRequest
{
    ParentAsLocationName = LocationName.FromProjectLocation(projectId, location),
    Processor = new Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1.Processor
    {
        DisplayName = name,
        Type = "CUSTOM_EXTRACTION_PROCESSOR"
    }
}, CallSettings.FromCancellationToken(cancellationToken));

and the snippet to configure processor and its schema:
var documentSchema = new DocumentSchema();
var entityType = new DocumentSchema.Types.EntityType
{
    Name = "custom_extraction_document_type",
};
entityType.BaseTypes.Add("document");
entityType.Properties.Add(new DocumentSchema.Types.EntityType.Types.Property
{
    Name = "Property1",
    OccurrenceType = DocumentSchema.Types.EntityType.Types.Property.Types.OccurrenceType.OptionalOnce,
    ValueType = "string"
});
entityType.Properties.Add(new DocumentSchema.Types.EntityType.Types.Property
{
    Name = "Property2",
    OccurrenceType = DocumentSchema.Types.EntityType.Types.Property.Types.OccurrenceType.OptionalOnce,
    ValueType = "number"
});
documentSchema.EntityTypes.Add(entityType);
try
{
    var response = await _client.TrainProcessorVersionAsync(new TrainProcessorVersionRequest
    {
        ParentAsProcessorName = ProcessorName.FromProjectLocationProcessor(projectId, location, processorId),
        DocumentSchema = documentSchema,
        ProcessorVersion = new ProcessorVersion
        {
            GoogleManaged = true,
            DocumentSchema = documentSchema,
            DisplayName = "pretrained-foundation-model-v1.1-2024-03-12",
            State = ProcessorVersion.Types.State.Deployed,
            ProcessorVersionName = ProcessorVersionName.FromProjectLocationProcessorProcessorVersion(
                projectId, location, processorId, "pretrained-foundation-model-v1.1-2024-03-12")
        }
    }, CallSettings.FromCancellationToken(cancellationToken));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

As a result the processor gets created however it has no configured storage (I need google-managed storage) and the dataset with labels is never updated as well.
I tried using Google.Apis.Document.v1beta3 nuget and following snippets
var processorsResource = new ProcessorsResource(_client);
var request = processorsResource.Create(new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3Processor
{
    DisplayName = "test-processor",
    Type = "CUSTOM_EXTRACTION_PROCESSOR"
}, $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{location}");
request.Credential = await CreateCredentialsAsync(cancellationToken);

var response = await request.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

and following code to create a dataset
var processorsResource = new ProcessorsResource(_client);
var datasetRequest = processorsResource.UpdateDataset(new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3Dataset
{
    Name = $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{location}/processors/{processorId}/dataset",
    UnmanagedDatasetConfig = new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DatasetUnmanagedDatasetConfig(),
        State = "INITIALIZED"
}, $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{_configuration.Location}/processors/{processorId}/dataset");
datasetRequest.Credential = await CreateCredentialsAsync(cancellationToken);
var response1 = datasetRequest.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

var request = processorsResource.Dataset.UpdateDatasetSchema(new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DatasetSchema
{
    DocumentSchema = new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DocumentSchema
    {
        EntityTypes = new[]
        {
            new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DocumentSchemaEntityType
            {
                Name = "custom_extraction_document_type",
                BaseTypes = new[] { "document" },
                Properties = new[]
                {
                    new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DocumentSchemaEntityTypeProperty
                    {
                        Name = "Property1",
                        OccurrenceType = "OPTIONAL_ONCE",
                        ValueType = "string"
                    },
                    new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DocumentSchemaEntityTypeProperty
                    {
                        Name = "Property2",
                        OccurrenceType = "OPTIONAL_ONCE",
                        ValueType = "number"
                    },
                    new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DocumentSchemaEntityTypeProperty
                    {
                        Name = "Property3",
                        OccurrenceType = "OPTIONAL_ONCE",
                        ValueType = "datetime"
                    },
                    new GoogleCloudDocumentaiV1beta3DocumentSchemaEntityTypeProperty
                    {
                        Name = "Property4",
                        OccurrenceType = "OPTIONAL_ONCE",
                        ValueType = "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{location}/processors/{processorId}/dataset/datasetSchema");
request.Credential = await CreateCredentialsAsync(cancellationToken);

var response = await request.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

This creates the processor, however its storage is not configured, schema is updated in console however any attempt to process a document with processors ends with 500 internal error. Do anyone know the way to programmatically create the custom extractor with proper schema in gcp document ai?
